# MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql, command-line-interface

The purpose is to check if the email already exists in the database utilizing python and MySQLdb. I am using the variable mail to store the e-mail. The MySQL form is email. I have the code below:

```
if cursor.execute("select count(*) from registrants where email = " + "'"email2"'") == 0:
     print "it doesn't exist!"
```

What is wrong with this statement or how can I go about doing this?

Comment: What is wrong is that you're not feeding your SQL query to MySQL. You're just comparing its string value with `0`, which always returns `False`.

Comment: Yes larsmans, I noticed that shortly after I posted. I updated the command to also ignore "@" and "."'s for SQL.

Answer (score 3):

I hardly know where to start.

Just typing a string of SQL into a Python program doesn't somehow query the database. You actually have to open a database connection, instantiate a cursor, use that cursor to run the SQL, and fetch the result. All this is explained in the MySQLdb documentation.

Once you've done that, you'll still need to actually pass the email parameter from your form to the SQL statement, which you're not doing either.

Comment: yes, for the sake of not spamming the entire forum I limited the code to two lines as oppose to 50

Comment: Well, we can't help you determine what's wrong with your code if you don't show the real code.

Comment: I did show the only code that matters. The rest is correct as all my other sql statements work. If you can't answer the question from what was given, then move on.

Answer (score 0):

well that won't work because that's just the mysql query string. You have to execute this query using a mysql client receive the results and the test. Using [pymysql](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL) would be something like this:

```
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host,user,password,database)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select count(*) from registrants where email = ?") #you need to replace the ? with some actual value or the query will fail
result = cur.fetchone()
if result[0]==0:
    print "E-mail does not exist!"
```